# How do I render my current view?

Tags: rendering

I am in the modelling view, and I would like to render this view.
I don't want to do anything else or switch to something, I would simply like to render what I see here:

[image]

However, when I press Render -> Render Image, it renders something else instead. The angle is different. I guess Blender uses a keyframe in my animation. But I don't want that. I would like to render my current view instead.

[image]

I was thinking "Ok, perhaps Render Image always renders something specific, and there might yet be another command like "Render current view", but I don't find it.

Thank you if you can tell me how I can render what I see.

Edit: If I press Viewport Render Image as suggested, I see this, and it's not changing. What am I missing?

[image]

Comment: Are you using cycles or EEVEE render engine?

Comment: On the right side, I click the icon under the wrench tools, it says "Scene". There it says Render Engine: Cycles.

Answer (score 3):

If you do a *Render > Render Image*, it will render the camera view, so the render will depend on your camera position and focal. You can move your camera to your current view though, with a  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>0</kbd> but the camera needs to have the same lens focal as your viewport view if you want no difference.

Or you can go into *View > Viewport Render Image* instead and it will render the exact same thing as your view (it doesn't work in Cycles + Rendered viewport shading though):

[image]

From your current file, switch to *Object* mode, enable visibility and selectability of the collection called *Scene* in the *Outliner*, select *Camera_2*, in the *Properties panel > Camera > Lens > Focal Length*, you have a keyframe with the focal at 55 at frame 72, remove this keyframe and set it to 50 (or set the view focal to 55 as well). Now choose the view you want and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>0</kbd> to make the camera view match the view, or press <kbd>0</kbd>, in the *N panel > View > View Lock*, enable *Lock Camera to View* and move your camera until you have the view you want.

[image]

Comment: Super, thank you very much!

Comment: Unfortunately my render is empty, and it's not changing. I have added this info to my post, also a screenshot.

Comment: could you please pack your image (File > External Data > Pack Resources) and share your file? https://blend-exchange.com/ Also uncheck the solve button so that it's not marked as solved

Comment: OK my bad, View Render Image doesn't work in Cycles in Rendered viewport shading, so I guess you need to use the first solution (i.e. move your camera to your current view)

Comment: For some reason, it won't work for me. I click "Camera_2", then "N", then "View", then Focal length: 200, then Ctrl+Alt+0, then Render Image, but nothing changed.

Comment: The focal length of the view is in the N panel > View, the focal length of the camera, once you've selected it, is in the Camera panel > Lens. You need to have the same value for both if you want to make sure that when you'll press Ctrl Alt 0 you'll have the exact same view

Comment: Can you please tell me how to select the camera? None of the camera is active, so I don't know which camera I have to select. I press 0 and rotate the view, but when I then click Render Image, it still uses a different rotation, so I am not doing it correctly.

Comment: You can tell what camera is active if you go into the Scene panel > Scene > Camera, it's currently Camera_2 but it's animated so make sure that you've removed any keyframe

Comment: Phew... thank you. It's so complicated... so obviously what I want to do is simply not thought of, right?

Comment: My project is really complicated with an unusual structure. I would therefore like to delete this question, ok? But thank you so much for your input.

Comment: did you finally succeed? I've edited my answer if it ever helps...

Comment: No, the original author did a lot of changes to make it work. I don't know what he actually did. I guess the old structure was just unusual.